# Parsing question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, parsing, csv

I would like to use cCSVParse http://michael.stapelberg.de/cCSVParse

in my project. I receive csv data from internet and want to parse it and save to core data. cCSVParse seems to be appropriate class of it. But it can only read csv data from file. When I receive data from internet, I wouldn't like to save it to file. Is there any way to use it for parsing data from NSData or NSString?

Comment: I think Dave DeLong's [CHCSVParser](http://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser) does what you want.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507636/iphone-how-to-convert-csv-format-into-nsdata-or-nsstring/4520762#4520762).  Sounds like you would want to use his NSString extension.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but it is too slow. cCSVParse does it's job much better.

Comment: @Olga yeah, it's not the speediest of things.  I'm about to embark on a major optimization of it, so if you check back in a week or two, things may be better. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to surround the CSV data (one row at a time) with `[]` chars and parse it with a JSON parser.  (But note that this only works if the non-numeric data items are enclosed in quotes.)

Or you can simply use

```
NSArray* items = [csvRow componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

if the data items aren't enclosed in quotes.

Comment: If there are quotes, use the JSON approach.

Comment: I decided to use an additional php script to reduce the size od loaded data size. Csv converting to JSon can be done on server side as well. Json is much more convenient any way. Thank you for replies!