# csv to core data

Tags: database, xcode, core-data, csv

I'm new to core data. How do I go about importing a fileName.csv into an Xcode core data project.  What type of app should I start with. The data does not need to change. I should be able to search for a particular object and find it. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Firstly store csv file data to NSArray refer [convert-csv-format-into-nsarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507636/iphone-how-to-convert-csv-format-into-nsdata-or-nsstring) link.

Now to save a NSArray/NSMutableArray in Core Data refer [NSArray/NSMutableArray in Core Data](http://coderwall.com/p/mx_wmq) link.

Answer (score 1):

If the data does not change then I would suggest not using Core Data. You could import the csv data (search around on google, there are several csv parsers for Objective-C) and store that information in an NSDictionary.

Comment: why do you think it is better not to use Core Data with state data? For example if have 18 different static csv files with 500 rows in each, do you think it is better to store data in some *.swift file in the array constant variables?