# Creating programs in objective-c for excel files

Tags: objective-c, csv

I'm looking to create a program that will sift and sort through tabular data created in excel format. I would like to be able to iterate through several .csv files within a folder, and create dictionaries of information that can be used to generate metrics and reports. I've been developing for a couple of years now, and I've never had to use xcode for anything like this.

I am curious if this is an easy solution to manipulating data or is there a preferred way of dealing with data in this form?

Comment: So, you want to know how to initialize an `NSDictionary` with a `.csv` file?

Comment: First of all, csv files are not excel files.  CSV stands for comma separated values.

Comment: @Pranav - I don't think it even needs to be an NSDictionary, I think that you can initialize an NSData structure with a CSV file.  This way he could manipulate the data however he wishes.

Comment: I think this is a repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507636/iphone-how-to-convert-csv-format-into-nsdata-or-nsstring

Comment: @trumpetlicks Yeah, sorry about the confusion. I just reread my question and realized that I was suggesting that the two were one and the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CHCSVParser](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser) to read and parse the .csv files.