# How to efficiently initialize data in iOS/Core Data application with csv files?

Tags: ios, file, csv, core-data, xcode6

I am currently developing an iOS app using the Core Data Framework. I've already created my model and it's displaying the data inserted. 
What I want now is to initialize the data inserted with csv files. I read the csv files and each line is transformed into a Core Data object (NSManagedObject) that I insert in the database. 
The problem is that there are almost 15.000 lines to read and the application launching takes almost one minute.

Do you know any other way to do this efficiently ? Maybe my approach is wrong, if so, could you suggest me another one ? I've googled this for an entire day but I only found things like using the sqlite file generated by Core Data. But the thing is, I use Xcode 6 and it seems that, that doesn't work anymore.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Adding the code snipped

```
- (void) fillLanguages {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"langue" ofType:@"csv"];
    NSString * zStr =
    [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                              encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                 error:NULL];

    NSLog(@"zStr=%@", zStr);
    NSLog(@"path=%@", path);
    // extract the data line by line
    NSArray * zAryOfLines = [zStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    if([zAryOfLines count] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"zAryOfLines count = 0");
        return;
    }

    for (NSString * zStrLine in zAryOfLines) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            NSLog(@"zStrLine=%@", zStrLine);
            NSArray *lines = [zStrLine componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
            NSString *name = [lines objectAtIndex:0];
            [self insertLanguage:name];
        }
    }
}

- (void)insertLanguage:(NSString*)name {
    Language *language = [NSEntityDescription
                          insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Language"
                          inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    language.languageName = name;
    language.languageGrammar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Grammaire + %@", name];

    // inserting the words of this language
    [self insertLanguageWords:language];

    [_managedObjectContext refreshObject:language mergeChanges:YES];

}

- (void)insertLanguageWords:(Language *)language {
    NSString *lower = [[NSString stringWithString:language.languageName] lowercaseString];
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"teere_%@", lower];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"csv"];
    NSString * zStr =
    [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                              encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                 error:NULL];

    NSLog(@"zStr=%@", zStr);
    NSLog(@"path=%@", path);
    // extract the data line by line
    NSArray * zAryOfLines = [zStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    if([zAryOfLines count] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"zAryOfLines count = 0");
        return;
    }

    for (NSString * zStrLine in zAryOfLines) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            NSLog(@"zStrLine=%@", zStrLine);
            NSArray *lines = [zStrLine componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
            Word *word = [NSEntityDescription
                          insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Word"
                          inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
            if([lines count] > 1) {
                word.value = [lines objectAtIndex:0];
                word.frenchValue = [lines objectAtIndex:1];
            }
            else {
                word.value = @"n/a";
                word.frenchValue = @"n/a";
            }
            [language addWordsObject:word];

            [_managedObjectContext refreshObject:word mergeChanges:YES];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Inserting 15,000 rows will always be slow, regardless of the database system being used.  I think you need to do this in the background and provide the user with something to read in between, like some sort of tutorial or help screen.  Alternatively if you use sqlite then you could pre-populate the app bundle with a database and copy that into the app's document folder, which would take very little time.

Comment: How could I generate the sqlite file used to pre-populate the app bundle ? The process seems different with Xcode 6

Comment: The sqlite file needs to be populated using scripts, and the file added to the Xcode project and copied into the app bundle during the build.  At runtime the file then needs to be copied back out to the documents folder where it becomes *live*.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do that ? Or some code sample ? Or a link ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this steps:

- Create background thread and then pass NSManagedContextObject into thread
- Read full CSV file into single data object
- Then track that data into loop and read one-by-one line
- Create NSManagedObject in loop and insert into DB
- After completing above loop then in last call [context save:&error] method only one time.

May be you are reading one-by-one line from file, So it take time to open-read-close file operation.
Also save Code-data context at last of all operation. It also save time.

Comment: Why would you read the whole CSV into a single data object?  What's wrong with doing it a line-at-a-time and avoiding memory overflow?

Comment: You can look to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507636/iphone-how-to-convert-csv-format-into-nsdata-or-nsstring#answers

Comment: Yeah it's rubbish and will blow up if you want to insert 15,000,000 rows.

Comment: Because the files are in csv. And each line generates a data object . It's not the entire file that I store in a data object

Comment: @akdeveloper first read full file into nsdata/nsstring then read line-by-line from nsdata/nsstring and then create nsmanagedobject. Actually when you are reading 15,000,000 lines from file, it open and close 15,000,000 times. and therefore processor take time.

Comment: @Punita Why would you open and close the file 15,000,000 times?  What's wrong with `fopen()` * 1, `fread()` * 15,000,000 and `fclose()` * 1?

Comment: Actually, that's what I'm doing, I put everything into an NSArray that I read in afterwards. I've added the code in the question. Let me know what you think

Comment: @trojanfoe but fread() execute following steps each time:
1. load file into RAM 
2. set file pointer to particular position 
3. then read data
4. remove file from RAM

And therefore it taking processor time.

Comment: What actually was wrong was the fact that I was saving the context each time after I was inserting a NSManagedObject whereas saving the context once when all the operations were finished was fine too. It is 100x more efficient. Thanks guys for your help. I am going to update the code.

Comment: @Punita No, that's not what it does.  It reads a small amount of data from file into RAM and moves the file pointer.  You think `stringWithContentsOfURL` does things differently?

Comment: @trojanfoe, may be you are right. problem is not with fread() operation. Issue is with save Core-data object into loop and thats what 'akdeveloper' user fixed issue.